# Should one have to enter a reason for downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I've received a few downvotes on some answers and I've just been curious about the reasons for the votes. I'd love to see a mandatory comment for the reason of the vote, so that I could improve my future answers or questions.

The optimal way would be a textinput when a user clicks the downvote button asking for the reason, which would be shown somehow next to the question/answer, but I'd settle for even a comment.

Do you think this would be a good idea?

Comment: I always find downvotes on these questions ironic...

Answer (score 4):

See

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373)

There are hours and hours of discussion about this on meta.so if you're bored :)

Comment: Ah, it's pretty well discussed over there. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: "Pretty well discussed" is an understatement.